# Как убрать папку Main_Activity.java?

Tags: android, android-studio

Случайно зарефакторил Main_Activity.java, заметил уже когда появилась эта папка(только называлась она Products). Переименовал её в Main_Activity.java, не помогло, ctrl + z аналогично. Помогите...[image: картинка]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не папка.

Такая ситуация возникает, если имя файла не совпадает с именем класса в файле. Сделайте имя класса и файла полностью одинаковыми и проблема исчезнет

Comment: Сработало, но теперь он не узнаёт в нём java файл, а если добавить к названию .java, то проблема повторяется :((

Comment: Очень странно. Попробуйте удалить файл и создать его заново

Comment: Я не понял, как так получилось, после удаления файл был нормальным, я вставил код, который был до этого, и сразу же проблема вернулась. Android studio подчёркивал строку с AppCompatActivity, я в подсказках выбрал rename file и проблема исчезла. Ничего не понял, но главное что проблема решена, спасибо!